# Unity macos Catalina 向けへのbuild

Tags: macos, unity3d

Unityのプロジェクトをmacos catalina向けにビルドしたいです。
工夫せずにビルドすると64bit向けではないために開けません。

環境

- macos mojave
- unity version 2018.3.14f (or win10 education)

Unityのバージョンは変更できますが、macosをアップデートするつもりはありません。
winかmacのどちらかからビルドできれば満足です。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教授ください。